# How to convert any old python object instance into a SQL Alchemy Table?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

For reasons that are too long for internet i need the below method and iam not sure how to do it without creating pages and pages of code. is there any logical and humanly sane possible way of doing this

```
a = Car(brand="bmw", year=1989, color="beige") 
b = Person(name="john Doe", age=32)
metadata = make_data_correct_way()
declarative_base_instance = make_declarative_base_the_correct_way()

def create_sqlalchemy_tbl(object, name):
    column_dict = do_some_magic_to_find_out_what_type_of_column_is_needed(object) 
    tbl_to_be_created = type(name, (declarative_base_instance,), column_dict)
    metadata.create_all()
```

currently iam using a dict of association between python types and sqlalchemy types, however thats a bit tedious and i dont know how to embed the primary_column . my first solution was to make a convention that if the object has the attribute "id" use that as as the pk column and if not create it with `id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)`